# sap.m.RatingIndicator Has Inaccurate Clicking Area

Tags: sapui5

I have a [sap.m.RatingIndicator](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.RatingIndicator/preview) in my SAPUI5 application.
Everything works fine except of the clicking area. When I click in the center or right, the correct star reacts. But when I click in the left corner of a star, the star left of the clicked star reacts.

So, is this the normal behavior or a bug in my code? Is it possible to fix?

```xml
<RatingIndicator id="rating"
  class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"
  maxValue="5"
  value="1"
  change="rate"
  iconSize="2rem"
/>
```

[image: The first star reacts]

The first star reacts if I click on the second (left tip)

Comment: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1974

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is [fixed](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/ca34e27deb4204018e3fe4e44a1f15447d648542) now. The threshold (to calculate the actual value) is now increased from `0.25` to `0.4`.

> ```js
> if (fValue < this.getMaxValue() - 0.4) {
>   //threshold is increased to take into account the font's stroke width
>   fValue += 0.4;
> }
> ```

### Previous behavior

1. Given input value: 2.18
2. `Math.round(2.18 + threshold /*0.25*/)` ⇒ `Math.round(2.43)` ⇒ 2.

### Now

1. Same input value: 2.18
2. `Math.round(2.18 + threshold /*0.4*/)` ⇒ `Math.round(2.58)` ⇒ 3.

If there are any inconsistencies or regression due to the fix, please, let the developer know [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1974).